# Weird cURL behaviour in PHP

Tags: curl, php-7

I am facing a weird situation using SFTP protocol in cURL.
If I try to download a file using this option:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
```

The curl_exec function call will hang until the connection times out, but ONLY if the file that I try to download is empty (0 bytes), all other files works fine. If I remove the CURLOPT_PORT function call and instead set the port in the URL like so:

```
$remote_address = "sftp://$username:$password@$hostname:$port/";
```

It downloads all the files, including the empty ones.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: first attempt goes with port from the url string. `CURLOPT_PORT` is just an alternative. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PORT.html

Comment: @Deadooshka: Thanks for your reply. But should not both ways of setting the port number work?  And why is only happening for empty files?

Comment: What port you use? AFAIK the default port for the SFTP is 22, so first it takes 22, but that server may has another protocol on this port, with empty file issue.

Comment: The server uses port 2650. But yeah, 22 is the default port for SFTP. But as you mentioned, there may be some issues with empty files for some reason.